iMessage App (iOS17+) - presenting a modal clears the current views
Background
Apple changed the UX and UI of iMessage apps for iOS 17. I would describe it as might from a horizontal toolbar selection to a plus (+) button based list-menu.
Problem
When I present a modal over the existing MSMessagesAppViewController, if I dismiss, when the modal does the slide down, it reveals the previous view controller is blank.
Specific example
Fully programatic iMessage app (extension), I use a toolbar button to present the contact picker:
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: {self.shareAction()})

If you look carefully, you can see the current VC's views removed, before the presentation of the modal slides from the bottom up, but I think a lot of people would perceive until later...
When the presented modal is dismissed (in my app, this is usually via tapping the "cancel" button), the modal does a slide down, to reveal a blank view controller, where the displayed views appear to have been removed. The background color of the viewcontroller's view shows thru.
I've also tried this with an alert like
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Profile", message: "Foo?", preferredStyle: .alert)

The same behavior, except that the background becomes a medium grey (which I assume comes from the UIAlertController.
I've reviewed all the iMessage-app docs, and everything on modality and ViewController presentation, but I could not find any explanation.
I tend to think this behavior might be a bug, because as I have worked on this, sometimes the tool bar remains visible (and the button works), and other times, the toolbar is also vaporized.

This might have been going on earlier than before. I just checked on iOS 15.x test unit, it happens as well. This is iOS SDK 17, but in iOS 15, the older UX is provided by that version of Messages.app. I see the views disappear revealing the background color of the bottom view, before the modal presentation begins animation.
